# Angular 2 and routing issue

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-routing

I have a problem, related to routings :

> EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot find primary outlet to load 'HomeComponent'

Here is the package.json file :

[image: package.json file]

So, the router version is 3.2.0.

My app.module.ts file :

```
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { Location, LocationStrategy, HashLocationStrategy } from '@angular/common';
import { Headers, RequestOptions, BaseRequestOptions} from '@angular/http';

import { AppComponent }  from './app.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './components/home.component';
import { MonitoringComponent } from './components/monitoring.component';
import { MonitoringApiComponent } from './components/monitoringApi.component';
import { PerfComponent } from './components/perf.component';
import { TaciteComponent } from './components/tacite.component';

import { routing } from './routes';

class AppBaseRequestOptions extends BaseRequestOptions {
    headers: Headers = new Headers();

    constructor() {
        super();
        this.headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        this.body = '';
    }
}

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        FormsModule,
        HttpModule,
        routing
    ],
    declarations: [AppComponent, HomeComponent, MonitoringComponent, MonitoringApiComponent, PerfComponent, TaciteComponent],
    providers: [
        { provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy },
        { provide: RequestOptions, useClass: AppBaseRequestOptions }],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

My routes.ts file :

```
import { ModuleWithProviders }  from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { HomeComponent } from './components/home.component';
import { MonitoringComponent } from './components/monitoring.component';
import { MonitoringApiComponent } from './components/monitoringApi.component';
import { PerfComponent } from './components/perf.component';
import { TaciteComponent } from './components/tacite.component';

const appRoutes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        component: HomeComponent
    },
    {
        path: 'home',
        component: HomeComponent
    },
    {
        path: 'monitoring',
        component: MonitoringComponent
    },
    {
        path: 'monitoringapi',
        component: MonitoringApiComponent
    },
    {
        path: 'perf',
        component: PerfComponent
    },
    {
        path: 'tacite',
        component: TaciteComponent
    }
];

export const routing: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes);
```

My home.component.ts file :

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
//import { ROUTER_DIRECTIVES } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
    selector: 'home',
    templateUrl: 'app/components/home.component.html'
})
export class HomeComponent {

    constructor() {}
}
```

And in my app.component.html and home.component.html, i just add :

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

I heard that some people said that we have to add this code :

```
import { ROUTER_DIRECTIVES } from '@angular/router';
```

but unfortunately it seems deprecated on that component version.

Any advice/solution please ?
Regards

Comment: Provide us code, not screenshot of code.

Comment: You don't need to import `ROUTER_DIRECTIVES` now, they will available to use view as you already imported `RouterModule`

Comment: If you remove the <router-outlet></router-outlet> from your home.component.html, it works? Only leaving the router-outlet on your app.component.html.

Comment: @user1841787 I'll add that as the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` from your **home.component.html**

Happy coding!

Answer (score -1):

This error mean's you've defined the routes, but you've never defined the  router-outlet or you've defined it in a child component ( home.component ) but you haven't defined the child route for it , **so Angular is confused to find the primary router-outlet.**

So , you should remove the router-outlet from home.component , or if you need it there , you should define child routes.

Comment: Actually, i did, like i said, i put in the template html the tag `<router-outlet></router-outlet>`

Comment: check last line of routes.ts

Comment: Yes you have, but when you don't import the router module , the router-outlet doesn't mean anything to angular but just a html tag

Comment: Alright , you're right , this is because of the screenshots :D my mistake